# Why does "cp" complain about identical files when chaining with "find"?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find, cp

I have a `find` command as below that lists the matching files:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt"

./level2/file2.txt
./level2/level3/file3.txt
./level2/level3/level4/file4.txt
./level2/level3/level4/level5/file5.txt
./output.txt
```

Now I'm trying to copy each of the listed files to a specific folder by chaining with `exec`:

```sh
$ ls copy_here | wc -l
0

$ find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} ./copy_here \;
cp: ./copy_here/file2.txt and ./copy_here/file2.txt are identical (not copied).
cp: ./copy_here/file3.txt and ./copy_here/file3.txt are identical (not copied).
cp: ./copy_here/file4.txt and ./copy_here/file4.txt are identical (not copied).
cp: ./copy_here/file5.txt and ./copy_here/file5.txt are identical (not copied).
```

Can anyone help breaking down the sequence of execution to help understand the flow of execution better?

Comment: Replace `cp` with `echo` for debugging...

Comment: @FedKad, that won't work in this case. The issue is that the `cp` action copies the `.txt` files to `./copy_here` which is empty from the start and then tries to copy these files again when it gets to the `./copy_here` dir. Without the copy, the error won't occur and `echo` won't make you any wiser. Also, OP has effectively already done this as `-print` is assumed if no expression is provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because of the order `find` is doing things. What's happening in your case is that `find` searches your `levelX` directories first, finding the `.txt` files and copying them to `./copy_here`. (Btw, you should not rely on in which order `find` discovers things, so this sort of error may or may not occur. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order).)

The problem is when `find` then gets to `copy_here`, which at this point contains the previously copied `.txt` files. `find` finds these files and tries to copy them to the same directory, thus causing said error.

To avoid this, you could exclude the `./copy_here` directory from `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" ! -path "./copy_here*" -exec cp {} ./copy_here \;
```

(there are several other ways to exclude directories and patterns, too)

or tell `cp` not to overwrite existing files:

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" cp -n ./copy_here {} \;
```